# setTimeout behaves differently on Mac OS and Linux when using libfaketime

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, settimeout, libuv

When using `libfaketime` to alter the speed of time for a process, the timeout set by `setTimout` expires according to the altered time when running under Linux but according to the original system time when running under Mac OS.

In Mac OS:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=src/libfaketime.1.dylib DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=y FAKETIME="@2020-12-24 00:00:00 x3600" node

> setTimeout(() => {console.log('hello');}, 3600 * 1000); // Takes an hour
```

In Linux:

```
LD_PRELOAD=src/libfaketime.1.so FAKETIME="@2020-12-24 00:00:00 x3600" node

> setTimeout(() => {console.log('hello');}, 3600 * 1000); // Takes a second
```

While investigating this issue I noticed that `libc`'s `clock_gettime` function is polled by node.js (libuv?) under Linux but this function is not called when running under Mac OS. (I added some `printf`s to the `libfaketime` functions)

What is the difference in the implementation of node.js (libuv?) which causes this disparity in behavior between Mac OS and Linux? And why does this difference in implementation exist?

Another observation that I made is that when time is frozen using `libfaketime` the behavior of `setImmediate` and `setTimeout(cb, 0)` differs under Linux in that the callback is run when using `setImmediate` but not when using `setTimeout(cb, 0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely a difference in libuv. Darwin does not [support `CLOCK_MONOTONIC*`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/89cbbc895bb459c6ab5319fa86a32a9fecbf8744/src/unix/linux-core.c#L442), therefore [`mach_absolute_time()` must be called](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/89cbbc895bb459c6ab5319fa86a32a9fecbf8744/src/unix/darwin.c#L51) in order to get the current time. This ends up bypassing `libfaketime`, causing the client code to run at realtime on OS X.